# Mongodb Query in PHP - 1 document per line

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I need to see in the result 1 document per line

```
$cursor = $collection->aggregate(
    array('$group' => array('_id' => array('year' => array('$year' => '$dia')),'sesiones' => array('$sum' => '$sesiones'),'usuarios' => array('$sum' => '$usuarios')))
);
```

When I put this code:

```
var_dump($cursor);
```

The result is like this

```
array(2) { ["result"]=> array(8) { [0]=> array(3) { ["_id"]=> array(1) { ["year"]=> int(2016) } ["sesiones"]=> int(12930172) ["usuarios"]=> int(9943884) } [1]=> array(3) { ["_id"]=> array(1) { ["year"]=> int(2015) } ["sesiones"]=> int(18486839) ["usuarios"]=> int(15773531) } [2]=> array(3)
```

and i would like to see 1 document per line

thanks a lot

Comment: Please check PHP document about [Mongo Aggregate](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php). Documents will be included in **result** key

Answer (score 0):

you can either use

```
var_dump(iterator_to_array($cursor));
```

or you can do

```
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
display $doc
}
```